# count events by period and cohort

Tags: r, grouping

I have a data frame that consists of birth, death, and marriage dates. I want to create a table that counts the marriage events (not counting NAs) per cohort and marriage period. I also want to plot it.

this is the data:

```
structure(list(born = c(1795.63287671233, 1796.8606557377, 1769.47671232877, 
1800.32328767123, 1799.98904109589, 1784.53278688525, 1791.6602739726, 
1797.40547945205, 1797.01643835616, 1790.2, 1799.88767123288, 
1798.56438356164, 1798.91506849315, 1797.26575342466, 1795.6904109589, 
1790.2904109589, 1786.57534246575, 1783.97260273973, 1796.4262295082, 
1798.49315068493, 1797.95342465753, 1796.61202185792, 1791.99178082192, 
1793.53424657534, 1793.77808219178, 1789.06575342466, 1794.06301369863, 
1794.73698630137, 1792.03278688525, 1788.45628415301), dead = c(1878.04383561644, 
NA, 1846.00273972603, 1853.66575342466, 1875.04931506849, 1842.76164383562, 
1844.48633879781, 1870.34246575342, 1880.24863387978, 1858.39178082192, 
1861.77260273973, 1832.35245901639, 1821.50136986301, NA, 1873.25205479452, 
NA, NA, 1867.66301369863, 1848.45628415301, 1843.82465753425, 
1854.81095890411, 1858.34794520548, 1854.20821917808, 1873.32876712329, 
1847.61095890411, 1868.87158469945, 1863.57260273973, 1865.45205479452, 
1845.83835616438, 1860.96994535519), cohort = structure(c(9L, 
9L, 6L, 10L, 9L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 8L), .Label = c("1710", 
"1720", "1730", "1740", "1750", "1760", "1770", "1780", "1790", 
"1800", "1810", "1820", "1830", "1840", "1850", "1860", "1870", 
"1880", "1890", "1900", "1910"), class = "factor"), marr_date = c(1829.87945205479, 
1824.03825136612, NA, 1824.03825136612, 1837.8602739726, NA, 
1821.37808219178, 1821.37808219178, 1826.24657534247, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, 1827.32602739726, 1828.71857923497, 1820.77322404372, 
1820.77322404372, 1820.05464480874, 1825.51780821918, NA, 1828.87704918033, 
1828.87704918033, 1823.27671232877, 1823.27671232877, 1833.44931506849, 
NA, 1821.35068493151, 1821.35068493151, 1841.04109589041, NA), 
    birth_event = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), death_event = c(1, 
    0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), marriage_event = c(1, 1, 0, 
    1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0), Period_Marriage = structure(c(2L, 
    2L, NA, 2L, 3L, NA, 2L, 2L, 2L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, NA, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, NA, 2L, 2L, 4L, NA), .Label = c("1810", 
    "1820", "1830", "1840", "1850", "1860", "1870", "1880", "1890", 
    "1900"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("born", "dead", "cohort", 
"marr_date", "birth_event", "death_event", "marriage_event", 
"Period_Marriage"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 30L
))
```

I have additionally created columns that show a 1 if an event happend and a 0 if not. The period variable (Period_Marriages) is created from the marriage dates. And here is my unsuccessful trial to create the table...

```
data_new <- dplyr::summarise(data,cohort,Period_Marriage,sum = sum(marriage_event))
```

... saying that "Error in summarise_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Column `cohort` must be length 1 (a summary value), not 30". 
So how can I achieve my (kind of numerical lexis?) table?)

Answer (score 1):

do you mean something like this?

```
library( dplyr ) #or library( tidyverse )

df %>% 
  group_by( cohort, Period_Marriage ) %>% 
  summarise( sum = sum( marriage_event, na.rm = TRUE ) )

# # Groups:   cohort [?]
# cohort Period_Marriage   sum
#  <fct>  <fct>           <dbl>
# 1 1760   NA                  0
# 2 1780   1820                2
# 3 1780   NA                  0
# 4 1790   1820               15
# 5 1790   1830                2
# 6 1790   1840                1
# 7 1790   NA                  0
# 8 1800   1820                1
```

Comment: insert `filter(!is.na(Period_Marriage)) %>%` before the `group_by` to kick out the `NA` rows.

Comment: @LAP it isn't clear to me which NA's the TS wants to exclude...  so I choose to exclude NA's from the summation...

Comment: @BenMat tidyverse is just a collection of usefull packages (including dplyr)... just using dplyr will also work on my solution.. (but be sure to check out the tidyverse!! ;-) )

Comment: `tidyverse` allows you to conveniently calculate stuff for temporarily grouped data. This can be done with base R, but the `dplyr` way is simpler.

Comment: it is what I mean Wimpel, yes. is there away without tidyverse? or better: what does tidyverse exactly do here?

Comment: ahhh, got it! ;)

Comment: after installing tidyverse something happend. most of my other packages cannot be found or loaded anymore as "there is no package called pillar" anymore. A package I have never heard of. what´s going on here? "Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]) : 
  there is no package called ‘pillar’
In addition: Warning message:
package ‘readr’ was built under R version 3.3.3 
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘readr’"

Comment: Which version of `R` are you using?

Comment: "R version 3.3.2 (2016-10-31)"

Comment: @BenMat any reason why not to upgrade to the latest version?

Comment: because it does install the package "installr" (with which I would like to upgrade the version) but cannot find it when required. before installing tidyvers I had no such problems. I restarted everything without saving now but still the problem remains.